# Время активности меню

Tags: javascript, php

Как сделать, чтобы после 17.30 было не активно меню, сейчас оно не активно с 23:59 и до 07:00
(сайт http://www.nam-nyam.ru)

```
<div id='week_days'>
          <div class='calendar'>";
          $listDays = getDaysListArray();
          $listDaysNames = getNamesWeekDays(true);
          $next_week = ($_GET['week'] == 1?true:false);

          $start_i = 0;
          $stop_i = 7;
          if ($next_week == true){
        echo "<a href='".$current_sub['Hidden_URL']."' id='prev_week_button'></a>";
        $start_i = 7;
        $stop_i = 23;
          }
          //echo "<pre>";
          //print_r($listDays);
          //echo "</pre>";
          for ($i = $start_i; $i < sizeof($listDays) ; $i++) {
              if ($listDays[$i]['weekDay'] == 1) echo "<ul class='".($next_week==true?'nextweek':'currentweek')."'>";

              if ($listDays[$i]['lastDay']) {
                  echo "<li><span class='day type_a'>" . $listDaysNames[$listDays[$i]['weekDay']] . "</span> <span class='date type_a'>" . $listDays[$i]['date_text'] . "</span></li>";
              } else {
                echo "<li><a href='/catering/?curDay=" . $listDays[$i]['date'] . "' class='date " . ($listDays[$i]['isInit'] ? 'type_c' : 'type_a'). "'><span class='day type_b'>" . $listDaysNames[$listDays[$i]['weekDay']] . "</span>" . $listDays[$i]['date_text']. "</a>";
            }

              if ($listDays[$i]['weekDay'] == 7) {
              echo "</ul>";
              break;
              }
          }
          echo "</div>";
          if ($next_week == false){
          echo "<a href='/catering/?week=1&curDay=".$listDays[7]['date']."' id='next_week_button'></a>";
          }
          echo "
        </div>
```

Comment: @DeeM, ХэшКод это не фриланс биржа. Перефразируйте ваш вопрос, уточните, что сделали сами, что не получилось.

Comment: $start_i = 7;
  $stop_i = 23;

Изменял значения этих переменных это не помогает

Answer (score 1):

```
$start_i = 7;
$stop_i = 23;
```

Не? Ни на что не наталкивает?

Comment: Я пробовал, менять 23, но не знаю будет ли работать если напишу 17:30

Comment: @DeeM не знаю, тут весь код геморройный, по идее можно сделать проще всё.